# Confusion about a Statement on a variant of the Hardy-Littlewood Operator

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading the following statement and I am confused about what the $\sup$ is over (it's not written in the book):

> Let $H$ be the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. A useful variant is:
>   $$H^*f(x) = \sup\left\{ \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)|\,dy:B \text{ is a ball and } x \in B\right\}$$

What is the $\sup$ over? Isn't the term inside a fixed quantity? It's just the average on the ball of fixed size.

Comment: it's the sup of the given quantity, over all balls containing $x$

Comment: ah, so the $x$ is not fixed in this formulation? also add as answer, so i can accept!

Comment: $x$ is fixed. The balls are varying. You are calculating $ \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)|\,dy$ for each ball that contains $x$ and taking the sup of these numbers, then assigning this value to $x$, so in fact you have a function $x\mapsto H^*f(x).$